# Quiero el programa vuelva a hacer lo mismo del pricipio despues del do while, si es invalido lo que el usuario pone

Tags: c++

Yo lo que quiero es que cuando el programa este en el else, despues del cout, lo devuelva al usuario a lo primero, sin tener que cerra el progrsama y volverlo a abrir

```
include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int x, y, potencia = 1, i = 1;

cout<<"Digite la base:"<<endl; cin>>x;
    cout<<"Digite la potencia:"<<endl; cin>>y;


if ((x>0)&&(y>0)) {

   for (i = 1; i<=y; i++)
    potencia *= x;
    cout<< "El resultado de x elevado a y es igual:"<<potencia<<endl; // Aqui se hace la potencia.


} else {
   do{
 cout<<"numero no valido"<<endl; //Aqui se invalida la accion, si el usuario coloca algo "ilegal"
   }
     while ((x>0)&&(y>0));`introducir el código aquí`

 return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a incluirlo todo en un bucle while:

```
include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
   bool Resuelto = false; 
   do 
   {
      int x, y, potencia = 1, i = 1;

      cout<<"Digite la base:"<<endl; cin>>x;
      cout<<"Digite la potencia:"<<endl; cin>>y;

      if ( (x>0) && (y>0) )
      {
         for (i = 1; i<=y; i++)
            potencia *= x;

         // Aqui se hace la potencia.
         cout<< "El resultado de x elevado a y es igual:"<<potencia<<endl; 
         Resuelto = true;
      } 
      else
      {
         cout<<"numero no valido"<<endl;
      }
      
   } while  ( !Resuelto );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ,Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `goto` para ir a una línea que especificaste con un nombre cualquiera. Algo así:

```
include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int x, y, potencia = 1, i = 1;

REGRESAR:cout<<"Digite la base:"<<endl; cin>>x; //REGRESAR es el nombre de la etiqueta para identificar la línea.
    cout<<"Digite la potencia:"<<endl; cin>>y;


if ((x>0)&&(y>0)) {

   for (i = 1; i<=y; i++)
    potencia *= x;
    cout<< "El resultado de x elevado a y es igual:"<<potencia<<endl; // Aqui se hace la potencia.


} else {
   do{
 cout<<"numero no valido"<<endl; //Aqui se invalida la accion, si el usuario coloca algo "ilegal"
goto REGRESAR;//Vuelves a la línea con ese nombre
   }
     while ((x>0)&&(y>0));`introducir el código aquí`

 return 0;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!